# locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration doesn't get called

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

According to the documentation locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration will be called in this 2 cases:

> - The first time heading updates are ever requested
> - When Core Location observes a significant change in magnitude or inclination of the observed magnetic field

I have programmed compass application following

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449309572/4dot-digital-compass/id761371

tutorial and it works fine, but the locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration never gets called. I don't know what to think of it, that my device is perfectly calibrated? Even if that is so it should be called by the first rule, the first time heading updates are requested. didUpdateHeading and didUpdateToLocation get called normally, should I do something to initiate calls to the callback in question?

Comment: NSLog the `headingAccuracy` value that you are getting in `didUpdateHeading` to find out if your compass is already calibrated.

Answer (score 0):

LocationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration got called after few hours when I started to do some real life tests. So that answers my question, no I should not do anything to trigger this behaviour cause the callback gets called automatically in correspondence to the second rule in documentation. I am still not sure what happened to the first point of the docs, when was the first time that heading updates were ever requested...